# How to solve [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception

Tags: flutter

I am getting error about [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: Login failed. Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks in advance

Here is my code:

```
    Future<dynamic> loginWithGoogle() async {
        try {
          _authProvider = AuthProvider.Google;
    
          GoogleSignInAccount user = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
          GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
              await user.authentication;
     
          loginWithMediaSocial(googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken)
              .then((value) {
            if (value['errorCode']== 500) {
              String error = "Login failed.";
              throw Exception (error);
            }
          });
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
      }
```

Comment: check the exception printed from where. Is it in `catch` ?

Comment: yes. at catch but get the error [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: Login failed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the firebase documentation? I think in order to use Google sign in you should follow the steps mentioned in the firebase documentation and add the files googleservices.json before you use Google sign in.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did not use firebase

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to use authenticate  please try the following step.

The following solution works in flutter project:

```
 Step 1: Generate SHA1 and SHA256 keys. 
 Step 2: Add both the SHA1 and SHA256 to firebase. (in you app settings)
 Step 3: Download google-services.json to android/app in your project folder.
 Step 4: In your terminal run the command flutter clean .
 Step 5: Run your flutter app.
```

For more information, visit:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth
https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did not use firebase. The error message I get is from loginWithMediaSocial(). After that, I want to return the error to main.dart